# The fifth k-invariant of BSO(3)

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, lie-groups, cohomology

From work of Pontryagin and Whitney, as I understand it, the homotopy 4-type of $BSO(3)$ is $K(\mathbb{Z}/2,2) \times_{K(\mathbb{Z}/4,4)} K(\mathbb{Z},4)$, where the pullback is along the maps $\mathfrak{P}_2\colon K(\mathbb{Z}/2,2) \to K(\mathbb{Z}/4,4)$ (Pontryagin square) and the obvious $K(\mathbb{Z},4) \to  K(\mathbb{Z}/4,4)$. In particular, the $k$-invariant $k_4$ is given by the composite 
$$
K(\mathbb{Z}/2,2)\to K(\mathbb{Z}/4,4)\to K(\mathbb{Z},5)
$$
where the latter map arises from the short exact sequence $\mathbb{Z} \stackrel{\times 4}{\to}\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/4$

> Has the next $k$-invariant been identified in the literature?

This would be a map
$$
K(\mathbb{Z}/2,2) \times_{K(\mathbb{Z}/4,4)} K(\mathbb{Z},4) \to K(\mathbb{Z}/2,6)
$$
as $\pi_5(BSO(3)) \simeq \mathbb{Z}/2$. An obvious option would be (reduction mod 2 then) cup product. But there may be some other cohomology operation floating around.

---

**Edit:** For $BSpin(3) = BSU(2)$ the analogous $k$-invariant is given by the map
$$
K(\mathbb{Z},4) \to K(\mathbb{Z}/2,4) \xrightarrow{Sq^2} K(\mathbb{Z}/2,6)
$$

Comment: One might also wonder how this relates to the fifth k-invariant for $BSU(2)$, since $BSU(2) \to BSO(3)$ is an isomorphism in homotopy above dimension 2 -- in particular, are the "same"?

Comment: Another thought: it's most likely the sixth Stiefel-Whitney class $w_6$, but what _is_ the map?

Comment: In  "On universal relations in gauge theory", Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 348 (1996) 1329-1355,  Selman Akbulut computes the 6th stage Postnikov tower of BU(2).  While not exactly what you are asking, the techniques might be useful.

Comment: What do you need this for, David? I'm a little puzzled by your comment that "it's most likely the sixth Stiefel-Whitney class $w_6$", since $w_6$ doesn't exist in $H^*(BSO(3);\mathbb{Z}/2)$. Anyway, the computation shouldn't be too difficult, but the result will probably involve indeterminacy. A similar calculation for $MO(2)$ is carried out in "On the realization of the Stiefel-Whitney characteristic classes by submanifolds" by H. Suzuki.

Comment: @MarkGrant well, it was a guess. :-) I didn't know that about $w_6$!

Comment: @MarkGrant "the computation shouldn't be too difficult," sure, but this is not my area of expertise, so I need more than "you could do it yourself!" The reason I need it is that I'm pulling back $SO(3)$ bundles from a 4-dimensional manifold $M$ to $S^5$ along some $p:S^5\to M$, and whereas characteristic classes (equivalently, the 4-type of $BSO(3)$) are enough to classify bundles on $M$ , they vanish on $S^5$, so I think I need to look at the 5-type, and in particular the $k$-invariant, to see if I can detect non-trivial maps $S^5\to M \to BSO(3)\to BSO(3)[5]$ (they may all be trivial!)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Recall that $SU(2)\cong Spin(3)$ and $PU(2)\cong SU(2)/\mathbb{Z}_2\cong SO(3)$. Originally Woodward calculated the lower stages of a Postnikov decomposition of $PU(n)$ in  “The Classification of Principal PU(n)-bundles Over a 4-complex.” If I recall, his cacluations did not apply fully to the case $n=2$ and they were amended by Antieau and Williams in [On the classification of oriented 3-plane bundles over a 6-complex](https://arxiv.org/abs/1209.2219) [1]. I think the calculations they perform are as complete as exist in the literature.

[1] Topology and its Applications, **173** (2014) pp 91-93, doi:[10.1016/j.topol.2014.05.012](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.topol.2014.05.012), arXiv:[1209.2219](https://arxiv.org/abs/1209.2219)

Comment: So they come to the conclusion I come to, then actually prove it (I was working on instinct (!)) and then, in essence, show the relevant k-invariant is _not_ $w_2^3$ or $(Sq^1 w_2)^2$, but the third basis element for $H^6(BSO(3)[4],\mathbb{Z}/2)$, which has dimension 3. Hmm.